# IIS Physical Path Incorrect

Tags: iis7, iis, path, webmail

I have created a WebSite in IIS, with the following correct physical path: d:\inetpub\wwwroot\nameofsite.  When i try and browse for this site, I get a 404 resource missing error.  From the webserver, there error states it is looking for the resource in d:\inetpub\webmail\nameofsite.  When I move the resource to this location, it works.  I don't understand why it would claim the resources are in inetpub\webmail dir, when I never specfied it there.  I deleted the site, and created it again, in case I did it by accident, but it still does it.

Thanks in advance

[image: 404 error]

[image: IIS Advanced settings]

[image: IIS Basic Settings]

[image: Forwarding]

[image: IIS Binding]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a backslash `\` after the last folder.
Requested URL has a folder in it. `entitialviridordahsboard`

Are you looking to goto `d:\inetpub\webmail\entitialviridordahsboard\entitialviridordahsboard` ???

Error is from the Map Request Handler Change image 4 forward from `/entitalvirtidordashbord` to
`109.108.142.135`

`/entitalvirtidordashbord`:

[image]

`109.108.142.135`

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like your also hosting multiple sites with the same IP address. You can do this with port 80 and site bindings like you have in image5 however you cannot forward traffic to the sites ip address. You need to set your DNS records A name to point to the ip address not a forwarder.

Comment: Thank you Jamie.  I'll confess, i am predominantly a programmer, and website setup really is new to me, so you'll have to excuse my inexperience.  To answer your above question, I am looking to goto d:\inetpub\wwwroot\enitialviridordashboard, but it seems to be wanting to goto the webmail version, as per image 1.

Comment: sorry I meant, Jamin

Comment: Do you host the webmail on the same ip address? I assume the WebPortalSTW site.

Comment: By following you last comment about changing the DNS records A name, it now works a treat.  Now http://www.enitialviridordashboard.co.uk/ hits my holding page.  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Your most welcome!